# How can i make 2 divs over lap? CSS

Tags: css, overlap

Here is what i mean

https://i.gyazo.com/fd1ccf9afc162485f387fb9972a00cd1.gif

They are both divs floated to the right and i need the drop down box to overlap the other

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: well i did try before this z-index and position but i didn't know that i could also do right: 0px; with position. but i just didn't say it in the thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use position property like so :

```
position: absolute;
```

Comment: and probably some z-index tweeking

Comment: i tried z-index and i have it floated on the right because thats where i need it

Comment: Or `position: fixed;` doesn't matter really in this case I believe. NOTE: You have to set the coordinates of the element if you apply either one of them.

Comment: the thing about position is there a way i can make it on the right because when i do that it just goes to the left. and i need it on the right for like all of the different resolutions of like screens so is there a way i can use like a % thing with that?

Comment: position: absolute; right:0px;